# Как изменить вид ссылки типа index.php?cat=php в  Mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, чпу

Ссылка получается вот такая:

```
mysite.loc/index.php?cat=php&article=obrabotka_formy
```

Тобишь в коде `php` это так:

```
<a href='index.php?cat=".strtolower($name)."&article=".translitIt($value)."'>".$value."</a>
```

Как это переделать на:

```
mysite.loc/php/obrabotka_formy
```

Автогенератор выдал мне такое правило:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ index.php?cat=$1&article=$2 [L]
```

Ну почти такое, пришлось немножко (совсем чуть-чуть) подправить, но все равно оно не срабатывает. Не пойму, в чем проблема. `mod_rewrite` включен, а ни одно правило не срабатывает (вроде).

**updated**

Уже не знаю что и делать, может я с самого начала все неправильно задумал, создал [test.loc.rar](http://rghost.ru/39096267) для примера, там одно правило срабатывает, а второе нет, я его закомментил, так как оно делает редирект главной страницы, а по сути нужно то же что и с ссылкой на статью делать.

Comment: [Вот все подробно][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/

Comment: Может уже вынести этот пхплюбский mod_rewrite не отдельный форум? Надоели ежедневные повторы этой темы.

Comment: @karmadro4, мне кажется, что лучше что сделать типа папки в темах "помогите составить регулярку" в которой можно задать вопрос, получить ответ, но нельзя получить карму.  
Отдельный форум не нужен :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, дык папок-то здесь в принципе не предусмотрено. Я ужо предлагал изгнать уэб-разработчиков из храма науки на отдельный форум о примитивном программировании и примитивном администрировании. Или, как вариант, абстрактно посвященный регуляркам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуйте так.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1&article=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Не помню как обстоит дело с экранированием в mod_rewrite, поэтому прилагаю второй вариант.

```
  RewriteRule ^\/?([^\/]*)\/(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1&article=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Смысл этого правила:
У нас может быть в начале / , а может и не быть.
Все до первого / передаем как cat.
Все оставшееся до конца строки передаем как article.

Comment: да я все не так делал изначально, у меня же ссылка выводится с этой всей мишурой СРАЗУ! а я должен был сделать без нее и потом уже в mod_rewrite страдать по поводу.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1&article=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Если не получится, попробуйте способ с перенаправлением:

```
<?php 
   header('Location: ' . $url);
   exit;
?>
```

Можно еще попробовать такой вариант:

```
function MyFnc() {
   top.location=<url>
}
...
<a href='javascript: MyFnc()'>link</a>
```

ну или скрытые параметры передавать POST`ом... не могу просто понять конечную цель (кроме того, что хотите видеть эту строку **mysite.loc/php/obrabotka_formy**), что именно вы хотите в конечном счете получить, для чего такая реализация нужна?

Comment: возможно дело в самом модуле, а не в регулярках, как можно проверить его работоспособность, чисто минимальными усилиями, у меня возникли сомнения в том что он работает!? Т.е. в том что он подключен у меня есть какая-то уверенность, так как строчка с модулем расскомментирована и apache не выдает никаких ошибок, но вот сам факт того что ни одна регулярка не срабатывает меня настораживает.

Comment: может как-то через консоль чекнуть что модуль таки подключен и работает исправно? Или глянуть вообще какие модули подключились при старте.

Comment: Вы хотите модули проверить подключенные?

Comment: Определяем, читается ли .htaccess: набиваем туда любую чушь — 500-ая ошибка, значит, работает.
Определяем, включен ли mod_rewrite: пишем в .htaccess строку RewriteEngine On — 500-ю получаем, значит, не подключен.

Comment: Проверить, что пишется access.log и error.log

Comment: подключено, никаких ошибок, в смысле при RewriteEngine On, да и сам файл работает, так как если я в него бред какой-то напишу, то ошибку выдает. Может дело в регулярке, какую-нть по проще проверить бы?

Comment: **archi_sova**, вроде как блог, в этом же файле ставлю if (isset($_GET['cat']) and isset($_GET['article'])) { echo $content и пошло-поехало, не вижу в этом ничего не обычно, а строку да, ну удобнее же так через GET, я не пойму как я тогда без формы POST сделаю.

Comment: Да, без формы POST не отправите...

Comment: некорректное правило преобразования.  

    ^(.*)$
Не имеет второй группы.