# PHP Mysql правильно ловим ID + корретно делаем URL адрес + скрываем часть URL адреса

Tags: php, чпу

Понимаю что вопроса 3, но чтобы не спамить задаю все в одной ветке.

Есть сервис, на нем 5 динамических страниц `index`, `shell`, `article`, `order`, `buy` с одноименным названием таблиц. Соответственно таблиц у нас тоже 5 штук.

Каждая таблица имеет `id` и другие поля, в нашем случае важно только ID.

Сервис очень загружен посетителями и покупателями и чтобы его разгрузить я сделал отдельные шаблоны открытия подробной информации для каждой страницы.

То есть превью товаров пользователь видит на страницах `index.php` , `shell.php` `article.php` `order.php` `buy.php`  а при нажатии на превью, переходит на шаблоны подробного описания товара на отдельную страницу, которые указаны внизу

То есть для **index** - шаблон   `i.php`

Для **shell** - `s.php`

Для **article** - `a.php`

Для **order** - `o.php`

Для **buy** - `b.php`

**Вопрос первый.**

Как правильно конструировать ссылки чтобы потом не было проблем ловить ID через GET запрос?

Есть превью товара, на нем в цикле вставляю ссылки, чтобы по ним пользователь перешел на новую страницу и увидел полную информацию о товаре. При переходе по ссылке пишет ровно тот адрес URL и ID который нужен, то есть браузер показывает верный адрес и совершает переход на нужную страницу.

Ссылку <a href конструирую сейчас так:

```
<a href="i.php/article/<?=$id;?>">
```

`i.php` - шаблон страницы для отображения полной информации
`article` - название таблицы из БД.

Полный адрес получается к примеру таким: https://example.com/i.php/article/1

Пытаюсь на этой странице на которую перешел поймать ID - не получается.

$_GET['id']; и его вариации не работают. При этом при выводе массива print_r($array) ID и все остальные данные конкретно взятого объявления отображаются корректно.

**Вопрос второй.**

Собственно говоря как правильно ловить  ID из созданного нами URL адреса? ID стоит в конце URL ссылки.

Пример: https://example.com/i.php/article/581

Или это делается с помощью сессии???

**Вопрос третий.**

Как правильно скрывать часть ссылки URL от пользователей?

Сами понимаете ссылка вида `example.com/i.php/article/581` - это бред.

Нужно спрятать шаблон страницы, чтобы получилось так:

**example.com/article/581**

Сделал вот так в конфигах .htaccess, это не сработало.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^example.com/i.php/article [NC]
RewriteRule ^example.com/(.*)$ example.com/article/$1 [L]
```

Пытался и так, тоже не работает.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^example.com/i.php/article [NC]
RewriteRule ^example.com/(.*)$ example.com/$1/article [L]
```

Где `article` - это название таблицы, соответственно за ним идет ID к примеру  example.com/article/511

Объясните пожалуйста, не могу догнать, прогуглил кучу статеек по трем вопросам, тестировал все что там было описано, безрезультатно.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А причем тут многопоточность, которая в заглавии ? А в GET значение будет только если оно было передано как get параметр. если у вас ссылка article/581 то как по вашему php должен догадаться, что 581 это именно 'id' а не что то иное ? get параметры должны иметь вид article?id=581 так что надо либо правилами перезаписи сделать из части пути параметр, либо в скрипте самому разбирать $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: @Mike Исправил название. По создании ссылки - это <a href="i.php/article?id=<?=$id;?>"> так корректно?  А по остальным вопросам сможете помочь? А то реально мозги подкипать начинают)

Comment: @Mike   Ссылка получилась, теперь ID выводится по $_GET)) Спасибо. Главный вопросы остались все таки не отвечены, особенно сейчас вид ссылки таков: example.com/i.php/index/?id=3625   как убрать из URL вот эти знаки (?id=) ??

Comment: или я ничего не понял, или здась один вопрос, на который только на ruSO примерно пол-тысячи ответов - как сделать ЧПУ

Comment: но главная закадка - прич ему тут *база данных*

Comment: @Ипатьев  ответы которые я прогуглил я считаю сомнительными, писать ЧПУ в БД  - я думаю это бред сумасшедшего и далеко не наилучший вариант, я спрашиваю про наилучшее решение в этом плане, а не первое попавшееся, которых в поисковике море.

Comment: у тебя какая-то каша в голове. Во-первых, с чего ты взял что тебе здесь напишут "наилучшее"? Чем решение, которое написали тебе лично персонально на тарелочке в твоем вопросе, лучше, чем то, которое написали кому-то другому в соседнем вопросе?

Comment: во-вторых, откуда ты вообще взял какое-то "чпу в бд"? ЧПУ к БД никакого отношения не имеет. Это тупо адресация. Гугли снова

Comment: просто прочитайте несколько ответов на подобные вопросы, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/124754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-index-phpcat-php-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite/124812#124812 и вникните в суть происходящего...

Comment: По факту нужны только RewriteRule у которых слева стандартное регулярное выражение, а справа то, на что надо заменять. Где `$1` и т.п. обозначают то что поймано в круглые скобки в левой части. т.к. слева никаких i.php нет, то справа вы в любом случае должны дописать их сами. регулярные выражения можно тестировать на http://regex101.com

Comment: Для вашего случая можно что то подобное замутить https://regex101.com/r/FBs8je/1

Comment: @Ипатьев   здесь площадка ОТВЕТОВ НА ВОПРОСЫ ПО КОДУ, а не клуб поэзии. Если вам что-то не нравится, не пишите сюда свои фразы, которые никак не помогают ответу. ДОказывайте свою "гениальность" среди людей вашего уровня, а не умничая с новичками.

Comment: @Mike  Спасибо за ответ! Помогли! К сожалению не могу поставить отметку вверх по поднятию вашего ответа, так как мало рейтинга.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри

Через .htaccess переносишь весь трафик на index.php

Потом внутри index.php  ловишь ссылку через переменную $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Чистишь ее от всего что нежелательно .. html теги и т.п.

И в конце делишь ссылку через explode по /

Все.. получаешь массив с данными из УРЛ и все перебираешь как хочешь.

Comment: Cпасибо, ответ тоже пригодится.